# Finding $\iint_R|x+y|\,dx\,dy$ where $R=\{(x,y):|x|<1,|y|<1\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, absolute-value, multiple-integral

The question is:

> $$\begin{aligned}\\
> \text{Evaluate } \iint_R|x+y|\,dx\,dy \text{ over } R&:{|x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 1}\\
> \end{aligned}$$

In my book it is given like:

[image]

$$\begin{align}\\
&\iint_{\Delta ABC}(x+y)dxdy+\iint_{\Delta ADB}(x+y)dxdy\\
&{=\begin{aligned}\\
\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=-x}^1(x+y)dxdy+\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=-1}^{-x}&-(x+y)dxdy\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
\end{align}\\
\text{And so on..}
$$
$$\text{I can't understand this solution. Can anyone please explain this?}$$

How to deal with absolute value functions in double integrals?

Comment: It's using the definition of absolute value: when you are in the triangle $ABC$, then it's sure that $x+y \geq 0$ for every $x,y \in ABC$. Therefore $|x+y| = x+y$. The same is done for $ABD$, except this time $x+y \leq 0$ for every $x,y \in ABD$ and so $|x+y| = -(x+y)$. Now that you have split the integrals you can easily compute them. 

In general, when you have an absolute value into a double integral it is convenient to make a drawing like the one you posted to better see the value of the function in the domain of integration.

Comment: @LorenzoLiverani can you please tell me why they divided the region by $y=-x$ straight line?

Comment: Because it is the line where $y = -x$, i.e. $x +y =0$.

Comment: @LorenzoLiverani thank you. Now I understood this.